# Radix sort a list

Tags: python, sorting, radix-sort

I have a table containing:

```
table = [['BA','A'],['CC','AA]]
```

and I'm using radix sort to sort the string elements inside of each list within the table.

```
def radix_sort(L, i):

    if len(L) <= 1:
        return L

    done_bucket = []
    buckets = [[] for x in range(27)]

    for s in L:
        if i >= len(s):
            done_bucket.append(s)
        else:
            buckets[ord(s[i]) - ord('A')].append(s)

    buckets = [radix_sort(b, i + 1) for b in buckets]

    return done_bucket + [b for blist in buckets for b in blist]

print(radix_sort(table,0))
```

The problem I'm having is with the for loop segment of the radix code where it isn't accessing the string elements but rather the whole list.

I'm expecting an output as such:

```
[['A','BA'],['AA','CC']]
```

How do i modify the radix code in order to cater for two dimensional lists?

Comment: How do you want those lists to be interpreted? Do you want to sort like the first element of each list, or some concatenation of the strings within it? Or do you want to sort each sublist rather than the outer list? Or…?

Comment: @abarnert to sort each sublist rather than the outerlist

Comment: `print([radix_sort(t,0) for t in table])`

Comment: @clink You don't want `radix_sort` to cater for two-dimensional lists then, you want to loop over the sublists and call `radix_sort` on each. The most concise way to do that is a list comprehension: `[radix_sort(sublist, 0) for sublist in twodlist]`. But if you don't understand that, just write an explicit `for` statement.

Comment: @abamert AH! i understand how it works now! Thanks a bunch